# Freeing Node from LinkedList ( memory wise )

Tags: c, memory-corruption

When send the head of a list to a function that `free()`s the memory. The given error by the compiler is:

```
"HEAD CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#70) at 0x011BCC0
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of head buffer. "
```

I tried to `free()` only the first node just to see how it goes but its the same error.
The function the receiving the linkedlist itself:

```c
void freeListOfEmployees(EmployeeNode *head)
{
    EmployeeNode *ptr = head, *temp = NULL;

    while (ptr != NULL) { 
        temp = ptr; 
        ptr = ptr->next; 
        free(temp); 
    }

    head = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Most likely it's not the freeing that caused it, but some other manipulation of the pointers. We can't tell you what since we can't see your code. You need [to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), we can't do it for you. If you get a [mcve] you do not understand, post it and ask about it.

Comment: I would assume that error message is caused by some other code before you try to free everything.

Comment: An error like that is typically because you write outside of the allocated memory. How do you allocate memory for the nodes? How do you use the nodes and the data inside them?

Comment: When do you get that error? While you are within that function? Do you use the memory after freeing it? Setting `head = NULL;` has no effect after you leave the function.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys but the error only appears when calling to the function I posted and happen on the first interaction with the list.. if I comment out the call for that function, the error doesn't show up.

Comment: Here's free advice. Just because calling a function causes an error to manifest, doesn't mean the function caused the error to begin with. C is not so simple, especially when managing memory. So you *need* to do some digging.

Comment: Can we see how you're creating these nodes? Your previous question showed a `createEmployeeNode` function with a huge bug in it that was pointed out in a comment. We need to see how you fixed that bug.

Comment: *to see most of the code you can check my previous question here* – I (and most likely most of the users here) don't want to do your work by stitching together code fragments and guess what it currently could look like. Also, it is site policy, that a question must contain all information in the question itself for others to be able to reproduce the problem. I thus ask you again to provide a [mcve] in your question (one file, such that someone willing to help can copy&paste it, compile it and observe the behavior).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in `freeListOfEmployees` but in `createEmployeeNode`, more specicially in this line:

```
EmployeeNode *temp = (EmployeeNode *)malloc(sizeof(EmployeeData));
^^^^^^                                             ^^^^^^
```

You are allocating memory for an `EmployeeNode` but you ask for the size of an `EmployeeData`.

This would be correct:

```
EmployeeNode *temp = (EmployeeNode *)malloc(sizeof(EmployeeNode));
```

or better:

```
EmployeeNode *temp = (EmployeeNode *)malloc(sizeof *temp);
```

or even better:

```
EmployeeNode *temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);
```

This way there is no possibility to get the size wrong.

And the cast `(EmployeeNode*)` is not completly wrong, but useless.

And anticipating your next question: *why did the problem only occur in `freeListOfEmployees` and not before?*

Answer: because you're overwriting memory that does not belong to you which triggers so called "undefined behaviour", and once undefined behaviour has been triggerd, anything can happen. Undefine bahaviour includes "apparently woring fine".

Comment: The casting way is how my teacher asked us to do it, I can only assume there's better ways to actually do it :)
I tried to make it simple as you suggested last time in order to make it easier to follow and understand.
Thanks for the replay and explanation, many thanks.

Comment: The cast is useless (but it doesn't harm either), there isn't any benefit. And next time provide all information in the question.